# Calculating Surface integral of A Vector field.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Find the surface integral of

$F(x,y,z) = x^2\hat{i}+  y^2\hat{j} -z\hat{k}$ around the triangle with vertices

$(0,0,0) , (0,2,0) , (0,0,3)$

So, the equation of that triangle is actually just the straight line

$3y +2z =6$ in $yz$ plane

now, Normal vector  = $\hat{i}$

Using the formula

$\int F.\hat{n} ds = \int \int  x^2 dydz$

But on $yz$ plane $x =0$ so Surface Integral is zero.

So, final answer is $0$ .

Is this correct ? Can someone please verify ?

Thank you.

Comment: A triangle is not a straight line! But the surface *is* contained in the $yz$-plane and so the normal vector is $\pm\hat i$, depending on the orientation. You're right that $\vec F\cdot\vec n = x^2 = 0$ on the surface, and so the integral is $0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Yes, you are right! But I am taking the normal vector that points outside (I am assuming anticlock wise orientation) . So for that I am considering $\hat{i}$

Comment: Thank you! for that quick response